# How do I force the Alchemy API to process text in English?

Tags: python, api, entities, alchemy

When calling the Alchemy API for language processing, it's sometimes auto recognizing the wrong language. (The text has lots of names, which sometimes throws off the auto recognition.) I know the text is all English, so is there a way to force the api to process in English? You'd think there would be a simple parameter, but I don't see it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

try adding "language=english" to your request, I think I used that once

Comment: I can confirm that this works for other languages too.